# How to fix this error "E122: Function MyDiff already exists, add ! to replace it" after I source a vimrc file?

Tags: vim

I use a portable gVim on Windows. This error `E122: Function MyDiff already exists, add ! to replace it` shows after I source this `vimrc` file.

I try to fix it by replace `function MyDiff()` with `function MyDiff()!` in my `vimrc` file. The error is gone. But next time I start the gvim application. An error message box shows `Error detected while processing vimrc: line x`. Maybe I replace wrong thing. Any help will be much appreciated?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As explained in `:help :function` you must append a `!` to the `:function` command:

```
function! MyDiff()
```